# how to update fusion table dynamically from python

Tags: python-2.7, google-fusion-tables

I am working on a health care project we have a device which continiously generates values for the fields ACTIVITY AND FREQUENCY .The values need to be updated continously from python to google fusion table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite broad, you probably want to have a look at the documentation of the Google Fusion Tables API if you haven't so far: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using

Also it may be worth checking the quota section to make sure that Google Fusion Tables is indeed what you want to use:
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#quota

I'll be glad to try to help if you come up with more specific questions :)

EDIT: since there are quite a few questions around the topic, I'll add some "hints".

- A (Google Fusion) table belongs to a Google account. Your script must therefore include a step where it asks for your permission to modify data attached to your Google Account. You can therefore see your script as a web application which needs an authorization to achieve its goal. This web application will use the Google Fusion Tables API and therefore it must be registered in the Google API Console. You will find details about the process of registration and authentication with a Python script here: 
  https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/oauthfusiontables?hl=fr
- I just checked that this works and you can insert rows to a table thereafter, so you may  want to have a quick look at my script. Note that you can neither use my application credentials (which are by the way not included) nor my table as you are not authorized to edit it (it's mine!). So you must download your application credentials from the Google API console after having registered and adapt the script so it loads your credentials. Also, the script does not create a table (as of now) so as a first step you can create a table with two columns in the UI and copy paste the table id in the script so it will know in which table to write. Here's the script (sorry it's a bit of a mess right now, I'll do as soon as I can):
  https://github.com/etiennecha/master_code/blob/master/code_fusion_tables/code_test_fusion_tables.py

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sir I have tried using ur code in my python shell but it didnt work.I have used my client id and table id but it is not accepting.

Comment: File "C:/Python27/stack_over.py", line 41, in <module>
    dict_api_info = json.loads(open(os.path.join(path_current, 'client_secret_%s.json' %client_id), 'r').read())
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python27\\client_secret_970870116608.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'

Comment: it is showing the above error.I have placed the missing file but its of no use

Comment: It seems that you haven't changed the `client_id` (line 40). As a consequence, Python looks for my client secret file (client_secret_970870116608.apps.googleusercontent.com.json) in your folder "C:\Python27" (where I guess your script is) and can't find it. So you must make sure your client_secret_etc. file is there and change the number in the script at line 40. You may have to adapt the redirect_uri at line 41 too.

Comment: Request Details
from_login=1
cookie_policy_enforce=false
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables
response_type=code
access_type=online
redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/oauth2callback
as=-4fe7f4042ab60bc7
display=page
pli=1
client_id=595585847052.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0
hl=en

Comment: I have changed the client id.I have been using the rediret URI as https://www.example.com/oauth2callback whci was given at the time of client id is generated.It say the there is an mismatch in rediretc URI

Comment: WILL there be any seperate redirect URI or is it the same

Comment: I edited the script so you no more have to provide the redirect uri (it's stored in the client secret file and is idd the one you got when you registered in the Google API Console). When you run the script, you should get "Visit the URL below in a browser to authorize" with a URL. Copy paste this URL in the browser. Never mind the page/error message you get: you should obtain in url bar something like "https://www.example.com/oauth2callback?code=THE_CODE_YOU_WANT". Just copy paste the code back to Python after "Enter authorization code (parameter of URL):" (without quotation) and you're done.

Comment: Also make sure that Google Fusion Tables API in on in your Google API console: "https://console.developers.google.com" in your project, check APIs & auth/API: Fusion Tables API should be on.

Comment: Visit the URL below in a browser to authorize

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=595585847052-1c10olp3jso0jke3hf3cpdod1mvaq4l6.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables&response_type=code

Comment: when i did this it redirected me to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables?code=4/R4eAOjjXzRZ8kU637P15YiPgDlBd.UmJSTYFYQH8W3oEBd8DOtNANTmFxigI

Comment: i copied the thing after the code in tmy python program it has thrown the below error:

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\access_token.py", line 59, in <module>
    redirect_uri)
  File "C:\Python27\access_token.py", line 36, in retrieve_tokens
    request_open = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in error

Comment: Ok, it doesn't look that bad: you are now getting the code which was 4/R4eAOjjXzRZ8kU637P15YiPgDlBd.UmJSTYFYQH8W3oEBd8DOtNANTmFxigI when you last tried. I don't see why it would fail so please try again (make sure you copy/paste the full code) and if it keeps failing, check the content of `auth_code`, `client_id`, `client_secret`(keep this secret) and `redirect_uri` which are all part of the request that appears to fail (but they all should be right...)

Comment: Just to be sure: the code is to be pasted to the opened Python session, not to the script. Every time you run the script (at least for now) you need to go through the authentication step: copy paste the url to your browser to get the code in the url bar, and copy paste the code to your active Python session. Check the content of `dict_tables_info` to see if authentication has succeeded

Comment: I want to dynamically update the timestamp like each time a row is added its date and time should also be updated how can i do it

Comment: You can use datetime (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html ): `import datetime`, `current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()` creates a datetime object of the current time. You can convert it to a string formatted as you wish e.g. `str_current_datetime = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` or `str_current_date = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` and `str_current_time = current_datetime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` etc.

Comment: print "Incrementing to %d" % modval
   print " date modified to %s" %k
   data = {u'sql' : u"UPDATE %s SET FREQUENCY = %d ,DATE=%s WHERE ROWID = '%s';" % (k,table_id,modval,rowid)}

Comment: File "C:/Python27/stack_dynamic_date.py", line 124, in <module>
    data = {u'sql' : u"UPDATE %s SET FREQUENCY = %d ,DATE=%s WHERE ROWID = '%s';" % (k,table_id,modval,rowid)}
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: what will be my select statement be like 'sql': "SELECT FREQUENCY, ROWID,DATE FROM %s WHERE ACTIVITY LIKE '%s'" % (table_id, value)})))

Comment: i stored the date in variable k when i tried to add like (table_is,value,k) it throws error ALL THE VALUES ARE NOT FORMATTED AS string

Comment: I just checked that the following works: `data = {u'sql' : u"INSERT INTO %s(text_column, nb_column, gps_column, date_column) VALUES ('text_example', 8, '49.0 2.5', '%s');" %(table_id, str_current_datetime)}`. I'm going to update my script example on github accordingly. Your questions are a bit numerous/hard to read: asking a precise question is good way to know if the question really deserves to be asked or not (e.g. "TypeError: %d format: a number is required" => I'm sure you could solve this alone ;) ). I'm glad to help otherwise of course

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion actually I was trying to explain my problem in an elaborate way

Comment: extremely happy for the quick response

Comment: Great :) by the way, just in case: in the comments on stackoverflow you can use SHIFT+ENTER to go to the next line